# removing contents of div using Jquery "empty" doesn't work

Tags: jquery, listitem

I'm trying to remove contents of particular div which are basically list items and a heading by using jquery empty so that I could replace with new contents. What happens when I run the code is, the whole div element blinked and flash the replaced content and then the old one reappear. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Here's an excerpt of my code -

```
$("#msg_tab").bind("click",function(){
  $("#sidebar1").remove(); 
  var html=".....";
  $("#sidebar1").append(html);
 });



<div id="sidebar1" class="sidebar">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <h2>Messages</h2>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Compose New Message</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>      
      <li><a href="#">Unread</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Another question is, how do I write multiple line html code string in javascript so that java would recognize as a string value? Placing forward slash at the end is ok when the string is not a html code but, in html code, I can't figure out how to escape forward slash from ending tags.I've tried escaping it with backward slash but doesn't work. I would be appreciated if anyone could shed a light on this matter as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Hit the 101010 button to format code as code, don't paste it on 3rd party sites.

Comment: I needed an answer fast and didn't realize hand coding <pre><code> tags doesn't work and, as result, all those html tags being interpreted. So I used third party side. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding a click handler to a hyperlink that points to your current page.
After the click handler executes, the hyperlink gets clicked and the page reloads, resetting it to its original state.

You need to add `return false;` to your `click` handler to prevent the page from reloading.
Alternatively, you could change the href attribute to `href="#"`.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the wrong function. You want [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$("#sidebar1").empty();
```

[`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will remove the element entirely.

Alternatively you can use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to replace all the contents.

Your key problem however is you don't stop event propagation. Your link is:

```
<a id="msg_tab" href="" class="tab msgtab">MESSAGES</a>
```

No `href` means if you click on such a link you will navigate back tot he same page. Your event handler should be:

```
$("#msg_tab").bind("click",function(){
  var html=".....";
  $("#sidebar1").html(html);
  return false;
});
```

The `return false` is to stop event propagation, which is currently forcing a page refresh. That's why you're not seeing the update.

Comment: I did as you suggested but the result was basically the same. The new content just flashed for a sec and the old one reappear. :confused

Comment: nope. There is another code in the very same function which doesn't relate to this element. Anyway, I'll post the the whole page for you to see - http://pastebin.com/1N82qiXL

Comment: @Andrew I took a closer look at your code. See the update. I believe I've solved your problem.

Comment: you bet you did it :). I had a similar problem before when I used anchor as a button. Totally forget of it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

U can also use

```
$("#sidebar1").html("");
```

to empty the content of any particular div...